# Animation lags only on Galaxy Mega 2 phones

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I have created a sliding drawer animation that opens/closes and grows/shrinks at the same time. I am using ValueAnimator and inside of the AnimatorUpdateListener I am manipulating the view's margin to increase or decreate (grow/shrink) it's size. Simultaneously, the opening and closing is being handled by the ValueAnimator. For the Galaxy Mega 2 phone, this animations is very choppy; not smooth at all. All other phones, old and new, seem to work fine. Is there any way this can be resolved?

```
            // close drawer
            ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, 100);
            animator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
            animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                    float ratio = ((Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue() / 100);

                    // moves the drawer to the left and reduces its size by changing its margins
                    mDrawerParams.setMargins((int) (mLeftMargin * ratio), (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue(),
                            0, (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue());
                    rlDrawer.setLayoutParams(mDrawerParams);
}
```

And here is how I open my drawer

```
            // open drawer
            ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(100, 0);
            animator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
            animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                    float ratio = ((Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue() / 100);

                    // moves the drawer to the right and increases its size by changing its margins
                    mDrawerParams.setMargins((int) (mLeftMargin * ratio), (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue(),
                            0, (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue());
                    rlDrawer.setLayoutParams(mDrawerParams);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you changed layoutParams, on View called onRequesLayout, there are lags. You need change properties. Change translation_x, scale_x, scale_y property. For example:

```
Animator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(drawerLayout, View.TRANSLATION_X, 0, (float) );
```